# Android studio different screen sizes res folder

Tags: android

I have a question regarding android supporting different screensizes. I would like to know if it is necassary to add the different sw folder for example layout-sw24odp manually to support different dip modes. When I wouldnt add these folders would the application scale automatically in each device? Or do I need to provide the folder containing the layouts, to support different densitys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only necessary if you are not getting the results you expect for a particular mode. In general I'll have separate folders for drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and similar for layout- and values-, I'll only populate those if I have a layout that is not working the way I want on those devices.